# How to elegantly handle multiple continue statements inside for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have been working on refactoring of the entire codebase for one of the project. Basically modularizing the code into separate modules, classes with single responsibilities, breaking the spaghetti function into small small methods etc.

However, I want to know how can we cleanly/elegantly handle the below block of code which has *multiple if conditions with continue statements*. Idea is to make it smaller and clean. For other cases, I am using predicate wherever I am finding multiple *if-and* statements. But here the case is little different since they are printing different log messages with respect to different conditions.

```
def somefunc(*args, **kwargs):
    for p_key, p_det in somedict.iteritems():

            get_all_somevars(p_det)

            if somevar1 and somevar2 is None:
                continue

            if somevar3 is None:
                logger.info('some message')
                continue

            if somevar4 is None:
                logger.info('some message')
                continue

            somevar5 = x.split('\n')
            somevar6 = y.split('\n')

            somevar7 = do_something_2(somevar5, somevar6)


            if somevar7 is None:
                logger.info('some message')
                continue

            do_something_3()
```

Comment: I think it looks good.

Comment: It looks quite clear to me too! Are you sure that `if somevar1 and somevar2 is None` does what you want it to do?

Comment: @ReblochonMasque Yes, this is an working section in the code which I just replaced with the dummy names.

Comment: This may be suitable for codereview.stackexchange.com. I'd say even more than to Stack Overflow, because "clean", "small" and "beautiful" are at least partially opinions. However, you need to create a representative example. Your code simply doesn't cut it, because several things are not defined that are used.

Answer (score 2):

Some quality code review rejects multiple continue (more than 2 for example) inside loops.

When it occurs, you can wrap all these conditional into a separate method that will return true / false and log accordingly.

I don't know other way to clean up.

Edit : (pseudo-code)

```
def somefunc(*args, **kwargs):
    for p_key, p_det in somedict.iteritems():

        do_something_1()

        if should_skip_that_loop(args)
            continue

        somevar5 = x.split('\n')
        somevar6 = y.split('\n')

        somevar7 = do_something_2(somevar5, somevar6)


        if somevar7 is None:
            logger.info('some message')
            continue

        do_something_3()

def should_skip_that_loop(*args, **kwargs):
        if somevar1 and somevar2 is None:
            return True

        if somevar3 is None:
            logger.info('some message')
            return True

        if somevar4 is None:
            logger.info('some message')
            return True
        return False
```

Comment: Yes, I am using predicate for other conditions in the code, but here I don't see much sense of using predicate, since these are all separate conditions and each has some separate information to log. If you can give me an example of how to convert that it would be great. Thanks

Comment: @Poutrathor `checkConditions` sounds confusing. I would rather read `if skip_that_loop(args): continue`.

Comment: I think this is the best we can go forward with

Comment: @Guimoute I like to prefix methods' name with a verb to convey what it is doing. Also thanks for the styling. proposal : `should_skip_that_loop(args)`

Comment: @Poutrathor perfect. I too try to name my methods like you do, so that an outsider can understand the code by just reading at comments and methods names. In my opinion a "main" program should always read like an algorithm, with all the actual work done hidden away in functions.